# acf_form() unable to upload images in Gallery for the role authore, it is fine with admin

Tags: php, wordpress

My error is:

> You don't have permission to attach files to this post.

I'm using Theme my login plugin and advanced custom fields plugin. 
Using ACF plugin I'm uploading images to user profile in front end.
I'm unable to upload images/files to media from front end for the user role author. It is working fine for the user role admin in front end. What I'm missing

Comment: you might missed to read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: [This](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/solving-wp-media-upload-in-the-frontend-and-tml?replies=4#post-4851176) could be the answer :)